What is the translation of ear candy in French?
Context: music production.
From https://audient.com/tutorial/ear-candy-production-tips :

Ear candy: those scintillating elements of a mix that aren’t intrinsic to the track but add the kind of ear-pleasing, brain-tickling embellishment that would greatly detract from the overall listening experience if removed. From sparkling percussion hits and cheeky synth runs, to glitchy vocal licks, sine wave sub bombs and beyond, this is the stuff that turns a good tune into a great one – and our six techniques and concepts will help you make the most of it.

Ear candies can be achieved in a variety of ways.
What is the translation of ear candy in French?
Google Translate and Linguee didn't suggest any interesting translations.

Guimauve musicale is attested. Sucre d'orge musical would be truer to the English; I might risk it depending on the context. Please provide tentative translations with your posts: w/out them answers are a matter of opinion.

@FrançoisJurain La guimauve n'est pas une composante de la musique mais la musique elle-même, et de plus, c'est un terme péjoratif (http://www.english-for-techies.net/mainstream%20vocabulary/music.htm).

Ear candy is also: ear candy
Merriam Webster noun
: music that is pleasing to listen to but lacks depth

@Lambie Ça serait  ce qui est appelé depuis longtemps de la  Bubblegum.

As François is saying, it's going to be impossible to give a good answer without more context. There are already diverging opinions in the answers as to what ear candy refers to, even if a definition is given, so context would be important.

@Frank context: music production

Yes, but the definition you gives feels relatively positive, whereas in some comments/answers, ear candy seems to be perceived negatively.

ear candy is positive in hip hop or pop music production. In everyday language, it has another meaning. The MW definition is accurate.

I agree with Lambie, I haven't seen the term ear candy being used in a negative way in the context of music production.

Il n'y a pas de terme qui soit généralement accepté. On trouve bien "effets sonores", mais c'est précisément "sound effects"; il y a aussi le mot « bruitage », de « bruiter », et on considère qu'il signifie « effet sonores » (pluriel).

(Cambridge) sound effect noun [ C usually plural ]
in a radio or television programme or a film, one of the sounds other than speech or music that are added to make it seem more exciting or real


(bab.la)  sound effects {pl} bruitage

Donc, il s'agit de sons (ni vocal ni musical) qu'on n'utilise pas dans la musique elle-même. Cependant comme « ear candy », le but d'ajouter ces sons est de rendre l'œuvre plus intéressante.
Selon la définition suivante, cependant, l'effet sonore est aussi autre chose, apparenté, mais qui concerne directement la musique et qui est similaire au « ear candy » (qui pourrait l'inclure). Voir par exemple, immédiatement après la définition, cette vidéo, où « ear candy » est constitué en partie de bruits de la vie quotidienne qui sont transformés électroniquement.

(musicmot.com) effet (sonore) Terme générique désignant une modification des paramètres sonores d'un signal. C'est un moyen technique très utilisé en musique contemporaine (jazz, blues, rock, variété, etc.) servant à modifier le son original d'un instrument électrique ou électronique.
Les effets les plus utilisés sont: la réverbération, l'écho (delay), le phasing, la distorsion, le flanger, la compression. Pratiquement tous les enregistrements actuel utilisent les possibilités des effets sonores, soit au moyen d'expandeurs et de pédaliers multi-effets, soit par l'utilisation de pédales indépendantes.

Infinite ear candy (like Bonobo & Gold Panda) (début)
adding ear candy

(TLFi)  bruiter TECHN. AUDIO-VISUELLES, THÉÂTRE. Produire des bruits de la vie quotidienne ou des sons imaginés par divers procédés pour accompagner l'action d'une émission radiophonique ou télévisée, d'une pièce de théâtre ou d'un film.


(TLFi) bruitage  TECHN. AUDIO-VISUELLES, THÉÂTRE
A.− Action de bruiter.
B.− Souvent au plur. Résultat de cette action.

La définition de bruitage est la plus proche comme on parle alors de bruits mais aussi de sons, dont on n'a pas à exclure les sons musicaux ; c'est cependant un terme qui est essentiellement réservé à l'audio-visuel.
En conséquence on pourrait penser que le terme « bruitage musical » serait une possibilité, mais ce terme existe déjà, et dans cette définition « musical » est une qualité intrinsèque du bruitage. (bruitage musical)
Le terme « fioriture » s'applique au chant.

(TLFi) A.− MUS. Trait d'agrément (non exempt de mièvrerie parfois) ajouté par l'exécutant à une phrase musicale pour donner plus de charme à son interprétation ou faire valoir sa virtuosité.

Le terme « effet sonore », qui a été détourné de son sens premier une fois (définition ci-dessus), pourrait être détourné une seconde fois, mais ce n'est pas une possibilité qui paraisse bien intéressante.
De même qu'un terme entièrement nouveau a été créé en anglais, il faudrait créer un terme en français.
Des deux possibilités « effet(s) musica(l)(ux) » et  « enjolivement(s) musica(l)(ux), qui sont des termes descriptif utilisables, le premier semble préférable.
Il existe un terme dont on trouve une occurrence au moins, « fioriture musicale », qui serait peut-être le meilleur. (D'autres exemples pourraient être trouvés (https://www.google.com/search?q=%22fioriture%20musicale%22&tbm=bks&lr=lang_fr)), mais il ne semble pas y en avoir beaucoup).

(CAMION BLANC: BLACK SABBATH L'essor de la musique Heavy Metal)   L'aspect dolent et éthéré, né de la synthèse des power chords (avec leur connotation médiévale et absence de tierces), des tons entiers et de la syntaxe éolienne a été exploité par la plupart des groupes de heavy metal. Il représente en effet une fioriture musicale qui cadre parfaitement avec son esthétique d'un monde mystique ou surnaturel.

Addition (Encore une preuve possible que l'usage est très mal établi)
On trouve le terme « bruitage » ici, et il est clair qu'il s'agit d'un « ingrédient » musical ; duquel il s'agit est difficile à déterminer.

Pour faire simple, un morceau instrumental c'est un enregistrement sans le chant. On peut y entendre des bruitages, des cris, des hurlements, mais pas [des] paroles. Certains groupes laissent généralement leurs instruments s'exprimer mais lorsqu'un célèbre chanteur décide de se taire et de laisser la bande faire son show, le résultat peut être incroyable.

